# Matplotlib bar chart customisation for multiple values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts, figure

I have a list of tuples with the countries and the number of times they occur. I have 175 countries all with long names.

When I chart them, I get:

[image]

As you can see, everything is very bunched up, there is no space, you can barely read anything.

Code I use (the original data file is huge, but this contains my matplotlib specific code):

```
def tupleCounts2Percents(inputList):
     total = sum(x[1] for x in inputList)*1.0
     return [(x[0], 1.*x[1]/total) for x in inputList]

def autolabel(rects,labels):
# attach some text labels
    for i,(rect,label) in enumerate(zip(rects,labels)):
        height = rect.get_height()
        plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
            label,
            ha='center', va='bottom',fontsize=6,style='italic')

def countryChartList(inputlist,path):
    seen_countries = Counter()

    for dict in inputlist:
        seen_countries += Counter(dict['location-value-pair'].keys())

    seen_countries = seen_countries.most_common()

    seen_countries_percentage = map(itemgetter(1), tupleCounts2Percents(seen_countries))
    seen_countries_percentage = ['{:.2%}'.format(item)for item in seen_countries_percentage]

    yvals = map(itemgetter(1), seen_countries)
    xvals = map(itemgetter(0), seen_countries)

    plt.figure()
    countrychart = plt.bar(range(len(seen_countries)), yvals, width=0.9)
    plt.xticks(range(len(seen_countries)), xvals,rotation=90)

    plot_margin = 0.25
    x0, x1, y0, y1 = plt.axis()
    plt.axis((x0,
              x1,
              y0,
              y1+plot_margin))

    plt.title('Countries in Dataset')
    plt.xlabel('Countries in Data')
    plt.ylabel('Occurrences')

    plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)
    plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=6)
    plt.tight_layout()

    autolabel(countrychart,seen_countries_percentage)

    plt.savefig(path)
    plt.clf()
```

An idea of what the dict I feed in looks like is:

```
    list = [
    {
        "location-value-pair": {
            "Austria": 234
        }
    },
    {
        "location-value-pair": {
            "Azerbaijan": 20006.0
        }
    },
    {
        "location-value-pair": {
            "Germany": 4231
        }
    },
    {
        "location-value-pair": {
            "United States": 12121
        }
    },
    {
        "location-value-pair": {
            "Germany": 65445
        }
    },
    {
        "location-value-pair": {
            "UK": 846744
        }
    }
}
]
```

How do I:

1. Make things so one can read them - would the answer be a histogram with bins instead of a bar plot? Maybe stepping every 10%?
2. How do I make it so the tick labels and the labels above the bars (the percentages) don't overlap?
3. Any other insight welcome (e.g. bars with gradient colours, red to yellow)?

**EDIT**

I reduced the number of countries to just the top 50, made bars more transparent, and changed ticks to rotate by 45 degrees. I still find the first bar has a tick which crosses the y axis to it is unreadable. How can I change this?

[image]

Changed to `countrychart = plt.bar(range(len(seen_countries)), yvals, width=0.9,alpha=0.6)` and also `rotation=45` to the `.text()` argument in the `autolabel` function.

Comment: @Kaël I already rotate by 90 degrees though - see code :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the alignment of the autolabels:

```
def autolabel(rects,labels):
# attach some text labels
    for i,(rect,label) in enumerate(zip(rects,labels)):
        height = rect.get_height()
        plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
            label,
            ha='center', va='bottom',fontsize=6,style='italic')
```

Was changed to:

```
def autolabel(rects,labels):
# attach some text labels
    for i,(rect,label) in enumerate(zip(rects,labels)):
        height = rect.get_height()
        plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
            label,
            ha='left', va='bottom',fontsize=6,style='italic', rotation=45)
```

To get:

[image]